# Exporting Async API call to another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im'trying to seperate api call from return/rendering but when importing teams (which contains data) shows as undefined. Is it because of the async await function?
How can I export the data and map it in the return on Teams.js?
Is there a better way to seperate the Api call from the return/rendering component?

> FormTeams.js

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const FormTeams = () => {
    const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getTeams();
    }, []);

    const getTeams = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/teams`)
            return response.json()
                .then(data => {
                    setTeams(data)
                    setIsLoading(false)
                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return (<Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />)
    }

    const deleteTeam = async (id) => {
        try {
            await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/teams/${id}`, {
                method: "DELETE",
            }).then(response => {
                setTeams(teams.filter(team => team.id !== id))
                return response.json()
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    
    return {teams, deleteTeam}
}

export default FormTeams
```

> Teams.js

```
import { Link, } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import FormTeams from './FormTeams'

const Teams = () => {
   const {teams, deleteTeam} =FormTeams()

    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className='centered'>Clubs</h2>
            <div><Link to="/Teams/add" className="link">Add New</Link></div>
            <table className='teams'>
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th>№</th>
                        <th>Team</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    {teams.map((team, index) => (
                        <tr key={team.id}>
                            <td>{index + 1}.</td>
                            <td>{team.team_name}</td>
                            <td>
                                <ButtonGroup>
                                    <Link to={`/Teams/${team.id}`} className='link'>View</Link>
                                    <Link to={`/Teams/edit/${team.id}`} className='edit'>Edit</Link>
                                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => deleteTeam(team.id)}>Delete</Button>
                                </ButtonGroup>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Link to={'/'} className='link'>Back To Home Page</Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Teams
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're kind of close. There are a couple things you need to change:

1. As a matter of convention, components (anything which renders content) should always have a PascalCase name (`TeamsTable`), and hooks should have a name which begins with the word `use` and is camelCased: `useFormData`.
2. Another matter of convention: write your effect code all in one block:

   ```
   useEffect(async () => {
       try { ... }
       catch(error) { ... }
   }, []);
   ```
3. Make sure your effect declares the right dependencies. In your case, you are referencing the `BASE_URL` variable. And even though you know the value will never change, you still need to list it as a dependency for your effect:

   ```
   useEffect(..., [BASE_URL]);
   ```
4. Hooks should not render anything. So move your loader into the `TeamsTable` component.
5. You also need to make sure that you set `isLoading` back to false if there is an error. I highly recommend keeping "error" state too and updating it inside all `catch` blocks:

   ```
   const [error, setError] = useState(null);
   ...
   try { ... }
   catch(error) {
       setError(error);
       setIsLoading(false);
   }
   ...
   ```

#### Wrapping it all together (only showing relevant changes)

You should have a new `useFormTeams` hook instead of the `FormTeams` function you have now, and the `useEffect` call should be updated per my suggestions. You should also return the `isLoading` state:

```js
const useFormTeams = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    ...
    useEffect(async () => {
        try {
            // do async stuff
            setError(null);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
        catch(error) {
            setError(error);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }, [BASE_URL]
    ...

    return { teams, error, deleteTeam, isLoading };
};
```

And you will use your new hook as follows:

```js
const TeamsTable = () => {
    const { teams, error, deleteTeams, isLoading } = useFormTeams();
    ...

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Spinner ... />
    }
    if (error) {
        return <div>There was an error: {error}<div>
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank yaputra jordi and Ryan Wheale! I've spend so much time but didn't find the right method. I was just trying to make my project a bit cleaner but I had stuck in the GET method. I thought it would be easy because in my other components CREATE and UPDATE it was simplier maybe because first the user enters the values and commits which will send it in the Api Call(useForm) method but in the GET it didn't export the data, but tested both of your corrections and my page setted off. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is where useHooks to the rescue!

1. First, separate all the logics into a hook

```js
const useTeams = () => {
    const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);

    const getTeams = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/teams`)
            return response.json()
                .then(data => {
                    setTeams(data)
                    setIsLoading(false)
                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getTeams();
    }, []);

    const deleteTeam = (id) => {
        fetch(`${BASE_URL}/teams/${id}`, {
            method: "DELETE",
        }).then(response => {
            setTeams(teams => teams.filter(team => team.id !== id))
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return { teams, deleteTeam, isLoading }
}
```

2. Then use the returned values as props for the return elements

```js
const Teams = () => {
    const { teams, deleteTeam, isLoading } = useTeams()
    
    if (isLoading) {
        return <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className='centered'>Clubs</h2>
            <div><Link to="/Teams/add" className="link">Add New</Link></div>
            <table className='teams'>
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th>№</th>
                        <th>Team</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    {teams.map((team, index) => (
                        <tr key={team.id}>
                            <td>{index + 1}.</td>
                            <td>{team.team_name}</td>
                            <td>
                                <ButtonGroup>
                                    <Link to={`/Teams/${team.id}`} className='link'>View</Link>
                                    <Link to={`/Teams/edit/${team.id}`} className='edit'>Edit</Link>
                                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => deleteTeam(team.id)}>Delete</Button>
                                </ButtonGroup>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Link to="/" className="link">Back To Home Page</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

IMO, The core idea of react hooks is just to separate logics from rendering. And this is the perfect use case for your problem. The hooks provide as a blackbox of logics that may composed of multiple other hooks and can mainly used for providing data or do some behavior.

Comment: Thank yaputra jordi and Ryan Wheale! I've spend so much time but didn't find the right method. I was just trying to make my project a bit cleaner but I had stuck in the GET method. I thought it would be easy because in my other components CREATE and UPDATE it was simplier maybe because first the user enters the values and commits which will send it in the Api Call(useForm) method but in the GET it didn't export the data, but tested both of your corrections and my page setted off. Thank you very much! :)